# How to force device rotation in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, rotation

I want to force a device rotation in Swift.
I've read, that this code is supposed to work but it doesn't:
    `let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")`

Is that maybe an old version or why isn't it working?

Answer (score 3):

The *only* supported way to force a device rotation is to do a fullscreen presented view controller whose supported orientations are limited to the one(s) you want.

Whatever other hacky stuff you may read on this topic (such as setting the device orientation in the code you gave) is wrong and unsupported.

Comment: There is no way to set such value to a view controller