# iOS Swift UIViewController Rotation

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, uiviewcontentmode

I have a UITabViewController with three tabs. On one of the tabs, the user taps a button and a new UIViewController controller pops up in Landscape mode (for the user to sign their name using their finger).  After the user is finished, they tap a Finish button and finish() is called which closes the signing UIViewController.

The problem I am facing is the screen that the user returns to that was in Portrait mode is now in Landscape mode even though the screen is set:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask{
    return .portrait
}

override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}
```

and there nothing I can do to force rotation back to portrait.  I have read posts such as: [How to force device rotation in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39559090/how-to-force-device-rotation-in-swift) and as I understand it, there is nothing I can do to rotate the screen back to portrait?

Comment: try this! https://stackoverflow.com/a/41811798/6642629

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple. Write the following code and change orientation value in ViewControllers you want to programmatically rotate.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue //Change orientation according to your scenario
        UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    }
```